# HibernateProxy.toString lazy initialization exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting a weird error while I'm debugging my POC.
I have 2 entities:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICANT")
public class Applicant implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6060170457948717553L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "applicant_id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long applicantId;

    @Column(name = "application_id", unique = true)
    private String applicationId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", referencedColumnName = "application_id", insertable = 
    false, updatable = false)
    private ApplicationEntity applicationEntity;
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION")
public class ApplicationEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7300036359295729197L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "applicationEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Applicant applicant;
```

These classes has the repositories interfaces extending from CrudRepository, and in the `Applicant` repository I have a custom method to get the entity with the applicationId:
`Applicant findByApplicationId(String applicationId);`
But, when I'm debugging, I see the following message in the intellij debuguer on the `applicationEntity` attribute:

`Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate  org.example.postgres.jpa.model.ApplicationEntity$HibernateProxy$qa4PKx8V.toString()`

The value `qa4PKx8V` changes every time that I perform a new test.

I tried a lot of combinations in the `@Join` annotation, I've deleted the lombook annotations, I've used the `@Transactional` annotation either, but is always the same error.

A key point to note, is that I can get the data from the table with any error, I just see this message in the debugger, so my question is, this is a thing of intellij or something like that? Or I need to fix this with configuration or changing something in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly change `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER` in both entities, secendly check if you missed `@Repository` annotation in repository classes.

Comment: @Seldo97 are you seriously suggesting that the OP change the `EAGER/LAZY` fetching configuration, with all the potential performance implications, just to fix `toString()`?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you have an autogenerated `toString()` implementation?

In general, you should avoid referencing lazily-loaded properties in `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()` etc. Failing to do so will result in `LazyInitializationException` surprises like the one you're facing, triggered by the aforementioned methods whenever they try to access lazy properties outside of an active transaction context.

(This is indeed 'a thing of intellij', in the sense that although the debugged code is probably surrounded by a transaction, the Intellij inspector evaluates the expression on a separate thread where no transaction is active = no persistence context is open. Also, it will only happen with `@XxxToOne(optional = false)` properties)

Comment: This is a correct answer, particularly the second part related to IntelliJ debugger.